# The max value that gets returned is not based on the requested date, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, max

For school we have to make an assignment -->

"The mayor of Amsterdam wants to store the covid levels in the water of for day. He wants to be
able give you a date and then get the maximum covid level for that day. Your job is to implement
a way to store the input as a data structure so that you can store the readings for each day and
easily find the maximum.
The first element in the input is the desired date (e.g., ’2022-09-08;’). What follows is a list
of triplets, separated with a semicolon ’;’. One triplet represents one reading instance with the
structure ’date,id,covid level;’. Find the maximum covid level found in the sewage system on the
desired date and output the sensor ID and the covid level."

The program takes as input:

(string)’yyyy-mm-dd’, (int)sensor id, (int)covid level.
The expected output is sensor id,covid level.

For example:
input: 2022−09−08; 2022−09−08, 23, 371; 2022−09−08, 2, 3171; 2022−09−08, 12, 43; 2021−
03 −21, 4, 129

Output: 2, 3172

I have made some code, however my code returns the maximum value overall. How can i bring the requested date into the equation, specifically in the get_max() function. If anyone could help, that would be great! Below is my code. the required data structure is a dictionary!

```
def add_value(dict_obj, key, value):
    if key not in dict_obj:
        dict_obj[key] = list()
    dict_obj[key].append(value)
    #print(dict_obj)

# get maximum for specific day
def get_max(dic, datum):
    #for keys in dic:
        #if dic.keys() == datum:
            max_val = max(dic.values(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
        #max_key = next(k for k, v in dic.items() if v == max_val)
            return max_val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = input()
    input = input.split(";")
    requested_date = input[0]
    input.pop(0)
    data = []
    for d in input:
        date, id, value = d.split(',', 2)
        instance = (date, (int(id), int(value)))
        data.append(instance)
    new_dict = {}
    for element in range(len(data)):
        add_value(new_dict, data[element][0], [data[element][1][0], data[element][1][1]])
    print(get_max(new_dict, requested_date))
```

ps, don't mind the commented lines in the get_max function, i just have been trying some things, but nothing seems to work, idk what i am missing here.

Comment: pop() function returns the element as well, so you can simply write ```requested_date = input.pop(0)```

Comment: input = input() is going to cause you a whole heap of pain. Also, are you sure the input looks as shown in the question? The first date doesn't have an associated level or id. How does that input relate to the output? There is no 3172 value in the input

Comment: @Vlad "Find the maximum covid level found in the sewage system on the desired date" the first element in the input is the desired date we need to consider, hence the requested date = input[0]

Answer (score 0):

I would make it a two-dimensional dict, and would do it immediately in the loop where you read all data. Then you can use the max formula with a lambda to get the key where the max value is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = input()
    input = input.split(";")
    requested_date = input.pop(0)
    data = dict()
    for sensor in input:
        date, id, value = sensor.split(',', 2)
        date = date.strip()
        if not date in data.keys():
            data[date] = dict()

        data[date][int(id)] =  int(value)

    max_on_date = max(data[requested_date], key=lambda key: data[requested_date][key])
    print(max_on_date, data[requested_date][max_on_date], sep=', ')
```

Comment: That makes sense, but unfortunately we have to leave the code as it is. The 2 functions need to be in there and seperate.

Comment: you can just put the ```max_on_date = ...``` line with a return line that's similar to the print line in a get_max() function, and it'll function just the same. For the add_value() function, you can basically just use the code in the for loop, and in the loop just call the function. That should work as well.

Comment: the first part of putting it in the get_max() function is fine, but when altering the add_value function i get the error: "keyError": '2022-09-08'

Comment: Without seeing the full function it's difficult to say what's wrong, but I'm going to guess the ```if not date in data.keys(): \n data[date] = dict() ``` lines are where it goes wrong. For two dimensional dicts, unfortunately, you need to create the first key before you can access the inner dict. There's other solutions like defaultdict, but this if should work just fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary keyed on date. Each associated value should be list of tuples. Create each tuple in the form (level, id) to simplify finding the maxima

Something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = {}
    data = input()
    dd, *values = data.split(';')
    for value in values:
        date, ident, level = value.split(',')
        db.setdefault(date.strip(), []).append((int(level), int(ident)))
    if (values := db.get(dd.strip())):
        level, ident = max(*values)
        print(f'{dd} {ident=} {level=}')
```

**Output:**

```
2022−09−08 ident=2 level=3171
```

Comment: thanks this makes sense, but we have to leave the code as it is, the functions need to be separate. idk why, my teacher just wants this unfortunately

Comment: @mshschoonmaak If you leave the code as it is it won't work

Comment: I have got it to work, i changed the get_max() function!